# Replicate Import Symbology Matching Dialog in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, symbology, layer-file

In Arcmap I can render a layer with same symbolgy applied to different fields by way of re-importing the .lyr file and choosing a Value Field.  How can I replicate this  functionality in ArcObjects?

Answer (score 2):

Given an IFeatureLayer, "theLayer", one would cast to a IGeoFeatureLayer, then get its IFeatureRenderer and cast that to a IClassBreaksRenderer.  Then it is a simple matter to set the IClassBreaksRenderer's Field to the field to be rendered.

```
IGeoFeatureLayer lyr = theLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;fixed
IFeatureRenderer ifr = lyr.Renderer;
IClassBreaksRenderer cbr = ifr as IClassBreaksRenderer;
cbr.Field = "someFieldName";
```